# Call a Swift Singleton from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, singleton, swift

I'm having some trouble accessing a Swift Singleton from Objective-C.

```
@objc class SingletonTest: NSObject {

    // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
    class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SingletonTest()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }        
}
```

swiftSharedInstance can not be reached.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now I have the following solution. Maybe I am overlooking something that would enable me to access "swiftSharedInstance" directly?

```
@objc class SingletonTest: NSObject {

    // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
    class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SingletonTest()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    // the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC
    class func sharedInstance() -> SingletonTest {
        return SingletonTest.swiftSharedInstance
    }

    // Some testing
    func testTheSingleton() -> String {
        return "Hello World"
    }

}
```

Then in ObjC I can get the sharedInstance class method (after importing the xcode generated swift header bindings)

```
SingletonTest *aTest = [SingletonTest sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"Singleton says: %@", [aTest testTheSingleton]);
```

Comment: Try adding `@objc` in front of the class variable declaration and see what errors it gives you.

Comment: the main reason u have to add method for shared instance becouse u can't use swift structure in objective-C

Comment: @Jack Annotating the class variable with `@objc` works for me too.

Comment: ... as in I don't need a wrapper struct or a sharedInstance() method. I can access the class / static variable directly from Objective-C this way.

Answer (score 27):

[Nicky Goethlis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720047/nicky-goethals)'s answer is correct but I just want to add another way of Singleton creation termed as  **[One line Singleton"](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)** in Swift which I came across recently and it does not use `Struct`:

> Singleton.swift

```
@objc class Singleton: NSObject {

  static let _singletonInstance = Singleton()
  private override init() {
    //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
  }

  // the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC. (From OP's answer.)
  class func sharedInstance() -> Singleton {
    return Singleton._singletonInstance
  }

  // Some testing
  func testTheSingleton() -> String {
    return "Hello World"
  }
}
```

> SomeObjCFile.m

```
Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedInstance];
NSString *testing = [singleton testTheSingleton];
NSLog(@"Testing---> %@",testing);
```

Comment: This approach is not working for me and crashing app while accessing from ObjC file (In your answer this line : Singleton *signleton = [Singleton sharedInstance];)

Comment: In Swift 4.1 you don't even need the sharedInstance() method. You can just annotate your static 'singletonInstance' with @objc, and access the property directly from ObjC code. (This may have started earlier than 4.1; just toyed with it today.)

Comment: @DarrenBlack is correct, but needs to be marked as public

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5 and above**

```
final class Singleton: NSObject {

    @objc static let shared = Singleton()

    @objc var string: String = "Hello World"

    private override init() {}   
}
```

use in `Objective-C`

```
#import <ProjectName-Swift.h> // change ProjectName to actual project name 

NSLog("Singleton String = %@", [Singleton shared].string);
```

Comment: add import statement `#import <ProjectName-Swift.h>` in you Objective-C file

Comment: refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

To make members of the `SingletonTest` class accessible (`swiftSharedInstance` is a member of this class), use `@objcMembers` modifier on the class, or add `@objc` modifier directly on the `swiftSharedInstance`:

```
@objc @objcMembers class SingletonTest: NSObject {

    // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
    class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SingletonTest()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }        
}
```

Or:

```
@objc class SingletonTest: NSObject {

    // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
    @objc class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SingletonTest()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }        
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `@objcMembers` which did the trick! However, I'm not sure about bridging performance which could be completely impacted.

Answer (score 2):

After creating the `Bridging header`, be sure to have the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` set in your `Build Settings` from your app target. If the value is empty, add the following value:

```
$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h
```

You need add `@objc` `property wrapper` to your `singleton`:

```swift
@objc final class Singleton: NSObject {

    @objc static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    @objc func foo() { }
}
```

Then, in the `Objective-C` `class`, import the following:

```
// Replace the "App" with your Target name.
#import "App-Swift.h"
```

Finally, after compiling the project, you will be able to use your `singleton` from `Swift` inside your `Objective-C` `class`:

```objectivec
[[Singleton sharedInstance]foo];
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it. To use Swift classes in Obj-C you both need to `#import "SingletonTest-Swift.h` the generated header or forward declaration with `@class MySwiftClass`.

Additionally the class needs to inherit from an Obj-C class like you have don here with `NSObject` **or** be marked with `@objc` to expose it. You don't need to do both though, `@objc` is there to be a more granular option when choosing things to expose.

Apple has some [good documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75) on all of this and there are two different [WWDC sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) you can watch on the topic of Obj-C interoperability as well.

Comment: The problem with the code is that the instance does not get exposed. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set `sharedInstance` as `public`

```
public final class TestSwiftMain: NSObject {
    @objc public static let sharedInstance = TestSwiftMain()
    private override init() {}

    @objc public func test() {
        print("testing swift framework")
    }
}
```

**Using it in Objc**

```
[[testSwiftMain sharedInstance] test];
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 12 Oct 2022

ObcMember So you won't have to write objC behind every function

Swift Class

```
@objcMembers class SwiftHelpingExtentions: NSObject {

    static let instanceShared = SwiftHelpingExtentions()
        func testingMethod() {     
            print("testing")    
        }
    }
}
```

On objective C View Controller

1. import : `#import "App-Swift.h"`
2. Call The method:
   `[SwiftHelpingExtentions.instanceShared testingMethod];`