# How to share class with iWatch app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit

I'm working on a watch app for my iPhone app. The iPhone app has been developed in objective-c and the watch app is being developed in swift. I need to share part of my classes with my watch extension so I am adding the classes to the two different targets. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a singleton and build it to access in both Swift and Objective-C. The singleton can then be invoked app-wide. Here's a potential solution I found from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489075/call-a-swift-singleton-from-objective-c). Any information you could need can be assigned to the singleton from anywhere.

```
@objc class SingletonTest: NSObject {

    // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
    class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SingletonTest()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    // the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC
    class func sharedInstance() -> SingletonTest {
        return SingletonTest.swiftSharedInstance
    }
```