# Property 'sharedInstance' not found on object of type ClassA

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I am creating a swift framework. In that one class is like this as shown below.

```
 import Foundation
    @objc public class classA: NSObject {

    public override init (){
        super.init();
    }

/**
 Singleton intance is returned.
 */
    public class var sharedInstance: classA {
        struct Static {
            static let instance = popeye();
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

Now when i add this framework into a Objective c project and try to access "sharedInstance" i get this error.

**Property 'sharedInstance' not found on object of type ClassA.
Fix it Replace 'sharedInstance' with 'sharedInstance'**

But even if i try use Fix it, this issue isnt solved.

**NOTE:** This issue doesn't happen when i integrate this framework with a swift project!!!

I AM STUCK.. :(

Comment: Maybe you should mark variable as `public`?

Comment: even i tried that. Didnt solve the issue. 
and as i say this works fine when integrated with swift project. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489075/call-a-swift-singleton-from-objective-c

Comment: Thanks Sahil. Though this was only a minor tweak in my code worked fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to fix this with a minor change !! :)

- **Swift framework code**

  @objc class SingletonTest: NSObject {

  ```
  // swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
  class var swiftSharedInstance: SingletonTest {
  struct Singleton {
      static let instance = SingletonTest()
      }
      return Singleton.instance
  }

  // the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC
  class func sharedInstance() -> SingletonTest {
      return SingletonTest.swiftSharedInstance
  }

  // Some testing
  func testTheSingleton() -> String {
      return "Hello World"
  }
  ```

  }
- **Objective C parent project code**

  SingletonTest *aTest = [SingletonTest sharedInstance];
  NSLog(@"Singleton says: %@", [aTest testTheSingleton]);

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem.  At first the syntax highlighter in Xcode flagged the same error in Objective-C that you mentioned, but the code actually was built and ran fine.

However, there is a cleaner way of doing this.  In your code you are using a computed type property, which is evaluated every time you access it!  You work around this by introducing the `struct Static`, where you essentially do what could be done in `classA` itself, like this:

```
/**
 Singleton intance is returned.
 */
public static var sharedInstance: classA = popeye()
```

Here we used a stored type property, which is a recommended way to implement singletons, see here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html
And here is some documentation on different kinds of properties:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html